# "Get up and running" problems (Phonegap April 2012)

Tags: cordova

**After building some mobile web sites, I really wanted to take the plunge and start working with Phonegap.** I'm on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.7.3 installed. Got the latest versions of Xcode, git, ant and make.

Downloaded the latest phonegap version (which is the Cordova.dmg) from the phonegap web site and installed it, although I'm not sure where that went and whether I need to do anything else with it. I reckon that since I can see Single Page View as an iOS application option in Xcode, that should be proof enough that it installed properly. Right?

At any rate, I've looked for and Google-d basic phonegap tutorials, and the one that I really liked, because it speaks to me as a phonegapp newbie, with step-by-step instructions, was [PhoneGap Beginner's Guide](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-phonegap).

However, there are some issues that keep me from moving on. I get to the point of:

```
 $ git clone git://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone.git
```

And that's when the trouble begins. I get the following message:

```
Cloning into 'phonegap-iphone'...
  fatal: remote error: 
Could not find repository phonegap/phonegap-iphone
```

OK, so maybe the repository was down, and I started looking for other repositories. And I've git-downloaded a few available repositories . . . but neither one of them had a phonegap-iphone.git folder/branch or whatever it should be properly called. (Yes, I'm a git beginner as well.)

So I never get to:

```
$ cd phonegap-iphone
$ make $ open PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg
```

Is it because something is outdated?
Am I not getting access to the correct github repository?

Any pointers and/or links to up-to-date phonegap tutorials would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay a couple of things...

1. Welcome to Phonegap / Cordova!
2. Install that DMG, you will need all of the phonegap / cordova frameworks
3. Once installed I HIGHLY recommend you start following the Google Group ( lots of really great, smart people working to make the platform better ) [LINK](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/phonegap)
4. Now that you're installed launch xCode and you will see a Cordova project, select that and follow along with the getting started steps on the phonegap website.

**GETTING STARTED**

1. Install the Cordova.DMG
2. Open xCode and select Cordova Project
3. Give it your project name, and company should be com.yourName
4. Now run the app in the simulator, it will give you an error that says something like "No www folder or Index.html found.
5. Now go to finder and find the project's folder, you will see a new folder there called...'WWW' drag that into your xCode project. ( drop it into your Project Folder in xCode ) BE SURE when you do this that you check the "Create Groups for Any Folder" radio button as well as Copy items into destination
6. Now save and run the application again... BAM you'll get a notification that says something like Cordova is Running!
7. Thats it! Think of your www folder as a root folder on a server, you can nest things and have other folders.

Comment: **Thank you very much.** I'll check out the links and try that approach. Greatly appreciate your answer. Still, I'm curious as to why the "Could not find repository phonegap/phonegap-iphone" error occurred. Or are you saying that will all be explained in the Google docs?

Comment: Honestly you don't need to use GIT for anything other than plugins, and those are easy enough to just clone the whole repository and have your own version of them. The website will walk you through what needs to be done to get started. I've edited my answer to explain "getting started" its a TL;DR verison

Comment: Drew, you rock! Thank you for the additional information. Sometimes, when I start something completely new, I freak out when I find a book or tutorial, follow along and things start breaking. So your comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: not a problem glad I could help! :) I know the feeling, its always better to be pointed in the right direction at the start vs later so good luck and happy deving!